# How to implement two glsurfaceview at the same Context?

Tags: android, android-layout, glsurfaceview, multiple-views

How to implement two GLSurfaceView at the same Context?

I want to implement the multi-channel for playing video.

Comment: Have you tried putting two GLSurfaceViews side-by-side? What isn't working?

Comment: Yes, I putted two GLSurfaceViews in the same Context.

but only one work.

Comment: It might help to see the relevant part of your XML layout, and the code that does the setup for the two Views, pasted into your question.